# Check if line starts with digit then put those lines in a separate file using Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to check in bash if line starts with digit then put those lines in a separate file. I tried `^[[0-9]]` but it doesn't work.

Here is the code which I tried:

```
myFailedFile=/tmp/1.txt

myTestsFile:
177711 TESTING ...yahoo.tests.calendar.resources.scheduler.1
854756 TESTING ...yahoo.tests.calendar.resources.scheduler.2
* 2102637 DONE ...yahoo.tests.mail.contacts.add.3

while read line
do
    if ( [[ ${line} = "^[[0-9]]"* ]] && [[ ${line} = *".tests."* ]] ); then
        echo -e "${line}\r" >> ${myFailedFile}
    fi
done <"${myTestsFile}"

Expected output of myFailedFile:
177711 TESTING ...yahoo.tests.calendar.resources.scheduler.1
854756 TESTING ...yahoo.tests.calendar.resources.scheduler.2
```

Comment: See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)... a simple `grep '^[0-9].*\.tests\.' "${myTestsFile}" > "${myFailedFile}"` would do.. for whatever reason you need `\r`, use `sed -n '/^[0-9].*\.tests\./ s/$/\r/p' "${myTestsFile}" > "${myFailedFile}"`

Comment: see also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 on using while loop to read file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct operator to use regex in Bash script is `=~`. Moreoever you don't need to double `[` in range of characters. Try this:

```
while read line
do
    if ( [[ ${line} =~ ^[0-9] ]] && [[ ${line} = *".tests."* ]] ); then
        echo -e "${line}\r" >> ${myFailedFile}
    fi
done <"${myTestsFile}"
```

**Edit**:

But you don't need a Bash loop for that job. You can do it with a sed one-liner:

```
sed '/^[0-9].*\.tests\./!d' "${myTestsFile}" > myFailedFile
```

**Explanations**(from right to left):

- `!d`: do not delete
- `/^[0-9].*\.tests\./`: all lines that start with one or more digits and that contain `.tests.` string

Answer (score 3):

Without using regex you can use `glob` as this:

```
[[ $line = [0-9]* ]] && [[ $line = *".tests."* ]]
```

- `[0-9]*` matches a string start start with digits
- `*".tests."*` matches a string that contains `.tests.`

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
if [[ ${line} =~ ^[0-9] && ${line} =~ ".tests." ]] ; then
```

or

```
if [[ ${line} == [0-9]* && ${line} == *".tests."* ]] ; then
```